# Add new list item using pnp/sp

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, pnp

I have an SPFX client web part that opens a dialog box containing a couple of textboxes, and when the user clicks `Ok`, I want the contents of that dialog box added to a list as a new list item. The list itself is stored on another site collection.

Here is a summary of my code

```
import { Web, ItemAddResult } from "@pnp/sp";

private async _addErrorItem(){
    let web = new Web("https://tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/hubsite");

    web.get().then(w => {
        console.log("Web details: ", w);
        w.lists.getByTitle("Page Errors").items.add({
            Title: "Title",
            Description: "Description",
            Url: this.props.pageContext.site.serverRequestPath
        }).then((iar: ItemAddResult) => {
            console.log(iar);
            this.setState({hideDialog:true});
        })
        .catch((error:any) => {
            console.log("Error: ", error);
        });
    });
}
```

The `_addErrorItem()` is called when the `Ok` button is clicked on the dialog box. When this happens, I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getByTitle' of
>   undefined

In other words, it does not see the "lists" property of my web object that is returned from the `get()` promise.

Can anyone suggest what's wrong with this code?

Incidentally, where I write the web details to the console, I can see an object that looks somewhat like a SharePoint object (it contains properties such as WelcomePage and WebTemplate), but crucially doesn't appear to have the properties I need, such as lists.

Comment: Is the code executing in the same site / site collection in which the   “Page Errors” list exists?

Comment: in first A sync query web.get() , you will receive only web properties not the lists. you need to explicitly call to receive the list information and then do items.add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're requesting a web and then use the retrieved object to get a list. Just use the original web create with the Web contructor:

```
import { Web, ItemAddResult } from "@pnp/sp";

private async _addErrorItem(){
    let web = new Web("https://tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/hubsite");
    web.lists.getByTitle("Page Errors").items.add({
            Title: "Title",
            Description: "Description",
            Url: this.props.pageContext.site.serverRequestPath
        })
        .then((iar: ItemAddResult) => {
            console.log(iar);
            this.setState({hideDialog:true});
        })
        .catch((error:any) => {
            console.log("Error: ", error);
        });

}
```